# SharePoint Sandboxed Custom Workflow Activity to get value from another list based on multiple criteria

Tags: c#, sharepoint, workflow-activity, sandbox-solution

I'm trying to write a sandboxed custom workflow activity that would go to another list and get a value of a field based on values of multiple other fields combined.

**List A**

- State - lookup to States list
- City - lookup to Cities list
- Population - Number
- ... other columns

(essentially the combination of State and City makes the row uniquely identifiable)

**List B**

- Company - lookup to Companies list
- State - lookup to States list
- City - lookup to Cities list
- Affecting % of population - number (percent)
- Population Affected - Number field (to be filled in by the custom
  activity workflow)
- ... other columns

**Constrains:**

- I can't add Company field to List A due to unique / different
  permissions
- The lookup fields need to stay lookup fields and can not be
  transformed into single line of text fields.
- Due to the fact that the fields are of type lookup, I can't
  concatenate them with a simple calculated column.
- The solution must be sandboxed and not farm. We aren't allowed to
  deploy dlls, only .wsp

**Problem:**
What I would need is a sandboxed custom workflow activity that triggers on List B item added/changed. When triggered, activity grabs the State and City values from the item in list B, goes to List A and searches for a combination of the same State and City. When found, it grabs the associated population. Lastly it multiplies the population by the % from "Affecting % of population" and pastes that result into the "Population Affected" field.

**Bonus:**
At some point, I will also need a sandboxed custom workflow activity that triggers on List A item changed (the population field). When the population for specific State+City combination changes, the activity would go to List B and update all "Population Affected" fields that satisfy the same State+City for all companies (multiple rows).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an event receiver. Nothing you've stated above leads me to believe you need a workflow. Look over my blog to see your options:

http://mattbramer.blogspot.com/2012/11/binding-event-handlers-to-sharepoint.html

Comment: I suppose the code doesn't have to be in a workflow. As long as it executes, I'm fine with it being an event receiver. it does have to be sandboxed though. We will not be allowed to drop DLLs in GAC.

Comment: What I've suggested works in sandbox. I've used the technique I've blogged about a lot.  Did you try it?

Comment: I was able to hook sandboxed event receiver to the specific list as per the link to your blog. 
Now I'm searching the internet for the code that will fetch the data I need.

So far I found out that I'll be using:
`SPList list = web.Lists["List Display Name"];`

and

`SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
               query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Counter'>1</Value></Eq></Where>";
               // execute the query
               SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);`

now i'm trying to find out how to get the value from specific column out of the item[0]

Comment: If my answer helped you, you should mark it as such. The rest of your questions should be asked in a new question, so your questions stay helpful to others.